# Django 2.0 NoReverseMatch: not a registered namespace

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

My goal is to Create hyperlinks which would toss a keyword into a views function which would then pull a query from my db onto the page.

**GOAL: Press hyperlink which would give me query of a specific major.**

I was attemping to use the  converter,
So the goal was, 1 being the first step, 3 being final step.
Is this possible?

```
1) Click the hyperlink -> Major = Accounting

2)URL.py 
path(<str:Accounting/, views.Major, name=Major)

3)Views.py

    def Major(request, Accounting):
       major_choice = professor.objects.filter(Major = Accounting)
       return render(request, 'locate/major.html', {'major_choice': major_choice})
```

NOTE: I replaced variables with what I want it to contain "Accounting", you will notice inside the bottom views.py its called "Major".

**Index.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'locate:Major' 'Accounting' %}">Accounting</a>
```

**major.html**

```
<ul>
{% for major in major_choice %}
    <li>{{major.ProfessorName}}</li>
{%endfor%}
</ul>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        path('<str:Major/', views.Major, name='Major')
    ]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class professor(models.Model):
    ProfessorIDS = models.IntegerField()
    ProfessorName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ProfessorRating = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=4)
    NumberofRatings = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Major = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ProfessorName
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import professor


def index(request):
    professors = professor.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'locate/index.html', {'professors': professors})

def Major(request, major):
    major_choice = professor.objects.filter(Major = major)
    return render(request, 'locate/major.html', {'major_choice': major_choice})
```

Comment: Should it be `<a href="{% url 'Major' 'Accounting' %}">Accounting</a>` instead of `<a href="{% url 'locate:Major' 'Accounting' %}">Accounting</a>`?

Comment: I just tried what you said and now i'm recieving a different error message, I think that actually helped! django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'Major' with arguments '('Accounting',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['locate/<str:Major/$']

Comment: Please see my answer bellow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your url path to this:

```
path('<str:Major>/', views.Major, name='Major')
```

And in your html:

```
 <a href="{% url 'Major' 'Accounting' %}">Accounting</a>
```

in views:

```
def Major(request, Major):
   ....
```

Comment: Awesome! so that got the site to not crash when going to the locate app, but once i click the hyperlink, I get the following error, TypeError: Major() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Major' <- is this becuase its trying to query 'Major' verses 'Accounting'

Comment: can you please update your question with your view code :) ?

Comment: Sure, I have the view.py posted up there I'll place it at the very bottom to make it easier :D

Comment: YOU ARE A GOD AMONG MEN, I LOVE YOU